# SQL: Error in LIKE column for WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT `donations`.*, `contacts`.`first_name` AS contact_first_name, `contacts`.`last_name` AS
    contact_last_name
FROM (`donations`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `contacts` contacts ON `contacts`.`id` =
    `donations`.`contact_id`
WHERE 
 `contact_first_name` LIKE 
    '%test%'
```

However I am getting error `Unknow column contact_first_name in WHERE clause`. I see that I am  selecting first name as alias `contact_first_name` but still getting error.

Can anyone help as to what is wrong I am doing here ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT `donations`.*, `contacts`.`first_name` AS contact_first_name, `contacts`.`last_name` AS
    contact_last_name
FROM (`donations`)
LEFT OUTER JOIN `contacts` contacts ON `contacts`.`id` =
    `donations`.`contact_id`
WHERE 
 `contacts`.`first_name` LIKE 
    '%test%'
```

The reason for this is because `contacts.first_name AS contact_first_name` is being evaluated last so `WHERE` does not know about the alias `contact_first_name`
Alternatively you can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
     SELECT `donations`.*, `contacts`.`first_name` AS contact_first_name, `contacts`.`last_name` AS
           contact_last_name
     FROM (`donations`)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `contacts` contacts ON `contacts`.`id` =
    `donations`.`contact_id`       
) a
 WHERE `contact_first_name` LIKE  '%test%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
WHERE 
  `contact_first_name` LIKE 
    '%test%'
```

to

```
WHERE 
  `contacts`.`first_name` LIKE 
    '%test%'
```

The reason for this is that you can't use aliases in the `WHERE` clause.